# is it any quick way to install package in PyCharm using pip when using conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda

I am using conda as the Python3 package management tool, sometimes the conda repo did not contains some Python package. So I have to install it using pip, first I found the anaconda environment folder, the next step switch to the anaconda environment folder:

```
cd /usr/local/anaconda3/envs/pydolphin
```

then using this command to install package:

```
./bin/pip install musicbrainzngs
```

is there any short way to do this? is it possible to install it the PyCharm IDE the simple way? the PyCharm IDE using conda install by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First activate your conda environment:
`conda activate <env>`

This will switch to the version of pip installed in this environment. Then you can install using pip as per normal which will install it into your conda environment:
`pip install musicbrainzngs`